# JavaScript - create a unsorted array which contains sum of duplicate elements alongwith unique elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to create a new array from existing array. Condition is that if element is duplicate then sum those elements. Please see below example for details as may be I am not able to explain clearly:

Input:

```
var arrayA = ["2", "1", "4", "2", "5", "1", "3", "2"];
```

Output:

```
var arrayB = ["6", "2", "4", "5", "3"];
```

here arrayB[0] = sum of 2s (2+2+2), arrayB[1] = sum of 1s (1+1)

I tried a lot but not able to figure out how I can achieve this.

Please help!

Comment: If `arrayA` were sorted, this would be a much easier problem. So can you simply sort it as a first step? Also, does `arrayB` have to be in any particular order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```js
 arrayA = ["2", "1", "4", "2", "5", "1", "3", "2"];
 //make a set 
 var set =  new Set(arrayA);
 var arrayB = [];
 set.forEach(function(a) {
   //for each set find in the original arrayA
   var len = arrayA.filter(function(f) {
     return f == a;
   });
   //push in arrayB set element * number of it occurance in original array
   arrayB.push((+a) * (len.length));
 })
 console.log(arrayB)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrayA = ["2", "1", "4", "2", "5", "1", "3", "2"];
var arrayB = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
  if (arrayA.indexOf(arrayA[i]) === i) {
    var count = 1;
    for (var j = i + 1; j < arrayA.length; j++) {
      if (arrayA[j] === arrayA[i]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    arrayB.push(arrayA[i] * count);
  }
}

console.log(arrayB);
// [ 6, 2, 4, 5, 3 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by looping a first time to sum them up, and a second time to recreate the array:

```js
var arrayA = ["2", "1", "4", "2", "5", "1", "3", "2"];
var arrayB = sumDuplicates(arrayA);

console.log(arrayB);

function sumDuplicates(arr) {
  var obj = {}, res = [];

  for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++)
    obj[ arr[i] ] = (obj[ arr[i] ] || 0) + +arr[i]; // +arr[i] converts them to Numbers
  // Now, obj = {"2": 6, "1": 2, "4": 4, "5": 5, "3": 3}
  for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) 
    if(arr.indexOf( arr[i] ) >= i) res.push( "" + obj[ arr[i] ] ); // Back to String

  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var arrayA = ["2", "1", "4", "2", "5", "1", "3", "2"];
var tmp={};
for (var i=0; i<arrayA.length; i++)
    tmp[arrayA[i]] = (tmp[arrayA[i]]||0)+1;

var res=[];
for (var i=0; i<arrayA.length; i++)
    if(tmp[arrayA[i]]) {
        res.push(arrayA[i]*tmp[arrayA[i]]);
        delete tmp[arrayA[i]];
    }
```

res would be:

```
[6, 2, 4, 5, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Solution using map given below:

   ```
   var arrIn = ["2", "1", "4", "2", "5", "1", "3", "2"];
   var arrOut = sumOfDupl(arrIn);

   console.log(arrOut);

   function sumOfDupl(arr) {
     var mapKey = new Map();
     var mapSum = {};
     var resultArray = [];

     for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       mapSum[arr[i]] = (+ mapSum[arr[i]])?(+ mapSum[arr[i]] + (+ arr[i])): (+ arr[i]);
       mapKey.set(arr[i], 1);
     }

     for (var [key, value] of mapKey) {
       resultArray.push(mapSum[key]);  
     }                  

     return resultArray;
   }
   ```